# Creating a popup from an object without javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

thanks for your help in advance. I am very new in CSS, HTML, and javascript. We can say i'm just an enthusiastic blogger.

I would like to create a popup without using any javascript, only from html and css elements. Here comes the tricky part for me. I have an ad script in the widget section of my page. I want to make that ad script popped up to the middle of the screen 5000ms after the page was loaded. Without javascript.

The second thing that would be awesome, if this pop up would only be shown for the people who come from my other site. So somewhat i need to determinate the referrer of the traffic source.

I did not find anywhere css+html code with auto popup and the http referer codes that i found also did not work.

So anyone could help a desperate newbie girl in her big challange? :(
I know it's a complex request, any partial soultion appricated. Please be as detailed as you can be. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

You can use CSS animations for your first question to trigger a pure CSS Modal/Popup.

For your second question I have an idea which I have **not tested** yet, you can use a link to your website followed by a /#popup for the people that come from your other site. Eg. http://www.example.com/#popup.

This will trigger the `:target` pseudo-class since the hash of the url is the same as the id of our element, so it will apply the fade-in animation to your popup making it visible to the targeted audience.

You will find two code snippets below, one addresses completely your first requirement and even has a button to close it, how else would they continue enjoying your site?

The second code snippet is the solution I could think of with pure CSS  + HTML, it should address both your requirements, you can try and test it with a real url.

---

**CODE SNIPPET:** (Wait 5 seconds).

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}
#popup {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  background-color: royalblue;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: white;
  animation: mymodal 1s 5s forwards;
}
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.close:hover {
  color: black;
}
#popup-container:target {
  display: none;
}
@keyframes mymodal {
  to {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1050;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="popup-container">
  <div id="popup">
    <a class="close" href="#popup-container">×</a> I'm a popup.
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**CODE SNIPPET:** *NOT TESTED* (Cannot reproduce what it's intended to do, needs a url).

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}
#popup {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  background-color: royalblue;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: white;
}
#popup:target {
  animation: mymodal 1s 5s forwards;
}
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.close:hover {
  color: black;
}
#popup-container:target {
  display: none;
}
@keyframes mymodal {
  to {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1050;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="popup-container">
  <div id="popup">
    <a class="close" href="#popup-container">×</a> I'm a popup.
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT:**

> What do i need to add to this CSS code to prohibit the visitor to scroll in the page outside the popup? Also i don't want them to be able to click anywhere outside the box.

You would need to change the `:target` pseudo-class to target `body` so that you can use an animation that applies `overflow: hidden;`, this will prevent the user from scrolling when the popup is open. Then, when clicking the popup's close button you remove the animation set to `body` and apply `overflow: scroll;` (URL Method not supported).

---

**CODE SNIPPET:** (Wait 5 seconds)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
#ref-fb {
  animation: bodynoscroll 1s 4.6s forwards;
}
#popup-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: -2;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: mymodalcontainer 1s 5s forwards;
}
#popup {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  background-color: royalblue;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: white;
  animation: mymodal 1s 5s forwards;
}
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.close:hover {
  color: black;
}
#ref-fb:target #popup-container {
  display: none;
}
#ref-fb:target {
  overflow: scroll;
  animation: none;
}
@keyframes mymodal {
  to {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1050;
  }
}
@keyframes mymodalcontainer {
  to {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1040;
  }
}
@keyframes bodynoscroll {
  to {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<body id="ref-fb">
  <div class="main">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque auctor enim non arcu congue lobortis. Integer sed ipsum id elit porttitor auctor. Aenean tincidunt lorem ut nisl dapibus, non vulputate nisi faucibus. Donec justo diam, dictum sit amet
      eleifend eu, consectetur et eros. Nam ut tempus tellus. Praesent tincidunt tortor nunc, non iaculis orci pretium non. Sed id massa in odio egestas faucibus eget sed libero. Aenean quis faucibus eros, non convallis erat. Vestibulum accumsan, est
      eget viverra vehicula, tellus nulla aliquet ex, a tempus mi lectus et lacus. Phasellus sollicitudin orci eu lectus pellentesque, mattis commodo purus fermentum. Aliquam in dui sit amet elit maximus euismod.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque auctor enim non arcu congue lobortis. Integer sed ipsum id elit porttitor auctor. Aenean tincidunt lorem ut nisl dapibus, non vulputate nisi faucibus. Donec justo diam, dictum sit amet
      eleifend eu, consectetur et eros. Nam ut tempus tellus. Praesent tincidunt tortor nunc, non iaculis orci pretium non. Sed id massa in odio egestas faucibus eget sed libero. Aenean quis faucibus eros, non convallis erat. Vestibulum accumsan, est
      eget viverra vehicula, tellus nulla aliquet ex, a tempus mi lectus et lacus. Phasellus sollicitudin orci eu lectus pellentesque, mattis commodo purus fermentum. Aliquam in dui sit amet elit maximus euismod.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque auctor enim non arcu congue lobortis. Integer sed ipsum id elit porttitor auctor. Aenean tincidunt lorem ut nisl dapibus, non vulputate nisi faucibus. Donec justo diam, dictum sit amet
      eleifend eu, consectetur et eros. Nam ut tempus tellus. Praesent tincidunt tortor nunc, non iaculis orci pretium non. Sed id massa in odio egestas faucibus eget sed libero. Aenean quis faucibus eros, non convallis erat. Vestibulum accumsan, est
      eget viverra vehicula, tellus nulla aliquet ex, a tempus mi lectus et lacus. Phasellus sollicitudin orci eu lectus pellentesque, mattis commodo purus fermentum. Aliquam in dui sit amet elit maximus euismod.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque auctor enim non arcu congue lobortis. Integer sed ipsum id elit porttitor auctor. Aenean tincidunt lorem ut nisl dapibus, non vulputate nisi faucibus. Donec justo diam, dictum sit amet
      eleifend eu, consectetur et eros. Nam ut tempus tellus. Praesent tincidunt tortor nunc, non iaculis orci pretium non. Sed id massa in odio egestas faucibus eget sed libero. Aenean quis faucibus eros, non convallis erat. Vestibulum accumsan, est
      eget viverra vehicula, tellus nulla aliquet ex, a tempus mi lectus et lacus. Phasellus sollicitudin orci eu lectus pellentesque, mattis commodo purus fermentum. Aliquam in dui sit amet elit maximus euismod.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque auctor enim non arcu congue lobortis. Integer sed ipsum id elit porttitor auctor. Aenean tincidunt lorem ut nisl dapibus, non vulputate nisi faucibus. Donec justo diam, dictum sit amet
      eleifend eu, consectetur et eros. Nam ut tempus tellus. Praesent tincidunt tortor nunc, non iaculis orci pretium non. Sed id massa in odio egestas faucibus eget sed libero. Aenean quis faucibus eros, non convallis erat. Vestibulum accumsan, est
      eget viverra vehicula, tellus nulla aliquet ex, a tempus mi lectus et lacus. Phasellus sollicitudin orci eu lectus pellentesque, mattis commodo purus fermentum. Aliquam in dui sit amet elit maximus euismod.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque auctor enim non arcu congue lobortis. Integer sed ipsum id elit porttitor auctor. Aenean tincidunt lorem ut nisl dapibus, non vulputate nisi faucibus. Donec justo diam, dictum sit amet
      eleifend eu, consectetur et eros. Nam ut tempus tellus. Praesent tincidunt tortor nunc, non iaculis orci pretium non. Sed id massa in odio egestas faucibus eget sed libero. Aenean quis faucibus eros, non convallis erat. Vestibulum accumsan, est
      eget viverra vehicula, tellus nulla aliquet ex, a tempus mi lectus et lacus. Phasellus sollicitudin orci eu lectus pellentesque, mattis commodo purus fermentum. Aliquam in dui sit amet elit maximus euismod.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque auctor enim non arcu congue lobortis. Integer sed ipsum id elit porttitor auctor. Aenean tincidunt lorem ut nisl dapibus, non vulputate nisi faucibus. Donec justo diam, dictum sit amet
      eleifend eu, consectetur et eros. Nam ut tempus tellus. Praesent tincidunt tortor nunc, non iaculis orci pretium non. Sed id massa in odio egestas faucibus eget sed libero. Aenean quis faucibus eros, non convallis erat. Vestibulum accumsan, est
      eget viverra vehicula, tellus nulla aliquet ex, a tempus mi lectus et lacus. Phasellus sollicitudin orci eu lectus pellentesque, mattis commodo purus fermentum. Aliquam in dui sit amet elit maximus euismod.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque auctor enim non arcu congue lobortis. Integer sed ipsum id elit porttitor auctor. Aenean tincidunt lorem ut nisl dapibus, non vulputate nisi faucibus. Donec justo diam, dictum sit amet
      eleifend eu, consectetur et eros. Nam ut tempus tellus. Praesent tincidunt tortor nunc, non iaculis orci pretium non. Sed id massa in odio egestas faucibus eget sed libero. Aenean quis faucibus eros, non convallis erat. Vestibulum accumsan, est
      eget viverra vehicula, tellus nulla aliquet ex, a tempus mi lectus et lacus. Phasellus sollicitudin orci eu lectus pellentesque, mattis commodo purus fermentum. Aliquam in dui sit amet elit maximus euismod.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque auctor enim non arcu congue lobortis. Integer sed ipsum id elit porttitor auctor. Aenean tincidunt lorem ut nisl dapibus, non vulputate nisi faucibus. Donec justo diam, dictum sit amet
      eleifend eu, consectetur et eros. Nam ut tempus tellus. Praesent tincidunt tortor nunc, non iaculis orci pretium non. Sed id massa in odio egestas faucibus eget sed libero. Aenean quis faucibus eros, non convallis erat. Vestibulum accumsan, est
      eget viverra vehicula, tellus nulla aliquet ex, a tempus mi lectus et lacus. Phasellus sollicitudin orci eu lectus pellentesque, mattis commodo purus fermentum. Aliquam in dui sit amet elit maximus euismod.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="popup-container">
    <div id="popup">
      <a class="close" href="#ref-fb">×</a> I'm a popup.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

Comment: Thank you Ricardo! It is very resourceful and it is working :) Can i somehow cloak the CSS for those people who does not come from my other site? So when someone who does not come from my other site, and checks the source code does not see this css modifcation.

Or how can i serve different style.css for those who come from facebook or my other page?

 Thank you :)

Comment: Usually we use parameters in the url such as ref="f-book" to check from where the users are comming. You can pick this parameter with JS and create an if statement where you then define which stylesheet to apply. Eg: http://www.mtv.com/news/interactive/lost-highway/?xrs=_s.fb_main, here MTV uses xrs=_s.fb_main, with that parameter they can do whatever they like, such as creating a graph to know from where they get more visitors. Ppl would still be able to check your source files tho. I think there's a way to prevent this changing the htaccess, but honestly I'm not an expert in that subject.

Comment: Ah thank so much. What do i need to add to this CSS code to prohibit the visitor to scroll in the page outside the popup?

Also i don't want them to be able to click anywhere outside the box.
Thanks

Comment: I've made an edit with this requirement, make sure to check it out : )

Comment: Thank you Ricardo! I swear this will be my last question. 
I don't want them to be able to click on anything behind the popup until they close it. Maybe a grey background behind the popup with low opacity?
Thanks

Comment: My last edit has that overlay behind the modal already, preventing users from clicking anything else. : )

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use animations for that with 5s delay.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.popup {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #bada55;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  animation: opacity 1s forwards;
  animation-delay: 5000ms;
}
@keyframes opacity {
  0 {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="popup"></div>
```

2. It is not possible with only HTML and CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, for the second part i can use whatever i want. Any suggestion? I explained my situation in an answer. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part you can use CSS keyframes:

HTML:

```
<div id="popup">Hello World!</div>
```

CSS:

```
#popup {
  opacity:0;
  animation: animationFrames linear 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animationFrames{
  99.9999% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

For the second part I dont think its technically possible to get the referrer withought some Javascript, since CSS and HTML is presentational.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers :) First part is absolutely solved.

For the second part, I can use whatever i like to determine the source of the visitor, i did not write correctly sorry. Let me explain my situation.

I don't want to use javascript for the popup because the ad provider does not allow to put the ad in popup window. But without popup the ad is completely useless, no one notice it. So i try to avoid using javascript for the popup because i assume if a robot scan my site it will notice that the ad script was triggered by javascript. I assume it is safer using css.

When a person inspect my page, i also don't want him to notice that the ad is in a popup. So i figured, i want to show the popup only for the visitors coming from my other site, or for the visitors coming from facebook.
In this case, if someone directly check my page or via search engine there  would be no popup window.

I was wondering how can is serve different CSS for those people who come from facebook, or from my other site. In this case, for the inspector there would be absolutely no trail of the poup, cuz he would see only the original CSS.:)

Thanks